Why doesn't numpy.resize work? Something basic must be wrong here, can someone please advise
In the following code:
import numpy as np

myArr = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(myArr.shape, "\n", myArr, "\n")
np.resize(myArr, (6, 2))
print(myArr.shape, "\n", myArr, "\n")
np.resize(myArr, (4, 3))
print(myArr.shape, "\n", myArr, "\n")

All the print statements show the same shape (4,2)
In my code, I need to resize a numpy array from (*,15) to (4096,15) and fill the extra elements. But I seem to be stuck at the resize step!

np.resize returns a new array but you are not keeping it ...

myArr = np.resize(myArr,(6,2))

The .resize method works in_place, but the function version makes a new array.  If you can look at the [source] link in the docs to see what it is actually doing.  Also make sure you understand how it's filling the zeros.

resize is not used that much. Reviewing the docs I see that it will repeat the existing values.  So a (n,3) resized to (3*n,3) will makes 2 copies, same as vstack((x,x,x)).  resize isn't the only way of doing something like this.  Making the bigger array is one task, filling it is another.

That kind of resizing could be done with repeat or tile.

np.resize(arr, new_size) returns a new array which you are discarding, so the solution can be one of the following:

arr = np.resize(arr, new_size)
OR
arr.resize(new_size)


It should be:
myArr = np.resize(myArr,(6,2))

i.e., np.resize returns a new array.
